# MVC page with Bootstrap layout, after loading the page, automatically scrolls up a bit, how to avoid that

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, autoscroll

This is the main page

[image]

then after loading the page , it automatically scroll to this position.

[image]

This is layout page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse  navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("My Dashboard", "Index", "Client")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Domain Registration", "ClientRegistration", "User")</li>                
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Employee", "EmployeeList", "Client")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Work Hour Manage", "WorkHourManage", "Client")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Department", "DepartmentList", "Client")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Company", "CompanyList", "Client")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "UserLogout", "Login")</li>
                </ul>
                <div style="color: #ada8a8;float: right;margin-top: 10px;">
                    @{
                        var UserType = Request.Cookies["UserType"];
                        var UserName = Request.Cookies["UserName"];
                        if (UserName != null && UserType !=null)
                        {
                            <text>@(UserType.Value+"-"+UserName.Value)</text>
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @CommonFunction.GetCurrentDateTime().Year - Employee Tracking & Management Information System.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This is the index page, not only index moves, but all pages scroll up automatically

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Dashboard";
}

@Html.Raw(TempData["Status"])
<div class="HeadingSite">
    My Dashboard <div style="float:right;font-weight:normal;">@(Session["DaysLeft"]) Days Left</div>
</div>

<style>
    .noselect {
        -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
        -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
        -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
        -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
        user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
    }

    .box {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        .box > .icon {
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
        }

            .box > .icon > .image {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 2;
                margin: auto;
                width: 88px;
                height: 88px;
                border: 8px solid white;
                line-height: 88px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background: #63B76C;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            .box > .icon:hover > .image {
                background: #333;
            }

            .box > .icon > .image > i {
                font-size: 36px !important;
                color: #fff !important;
            }

            .box > .icon:hover > .image > i {
                color: white !important;
            }

            .box > .icon > .info {
                margin-top: -24px;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
                border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
                padding: 15px 0 10px 0;
            }

            .box > .icon:hover > .info {
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
                border-color: #e0e0e0;
                color: white;
            }

            .box > .icon > .info > h4.title {
                font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif !important;
                font-size: 16px;
                color: #222;
                font-weight: 500;
            }

            .box > .icon > .info > p {
                font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif !important;
                font-size: 13px;
                color: #666;
                line-height: 1.5em;
                margin: 20px;
            }

            .box > .icon:hover > .info > h4.title, .box > .icon:hover > .info > p, .box > .icon:hover > .info > .more > a {
                color: #222;
            }

            .box > .icon > .info > .more a {
                font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif !important;
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #222;
                line-height: 12px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .box > .icon:hover > .info > .more > a {
                color: #fff;
                padding: 6px 8px;
                background-color: #63B76C;
            }

        .box .space {
            height: 30px;
        }
</style>
<div class="row">
    <div onclick="location.href = '../Client/WorkHourManage';" class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="image"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h4 class="title">Manage Work Hour</h4>
                    <p>
                        Manage and view work hours of the company..
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div onclick="location.href = '../Client/CompanyList';" class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 noselect">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="image"><i class="fa fa-industry"></i></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h4 class="title">Manage Company List</h4>
                    <p>
                        Manage or view Company List of this company..
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div onclick="location.href = '../Client/EmployeeList';" class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="image"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h4 class="title">Manage Employees</h4>
                    <p>
                        Manage or view Employee of this company..
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div onclick="location.href = '../Client/DepartmentList';" class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 noselect">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="image"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h4 class="title">Manage Department</h4>
                    <p>
                        Departments are added to employee details..
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div onclick="location.href = '../Client/EmployeeBackgroundTrackHistory';" class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 noselect">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="image"><i class="fa fa-street-view"></i></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h4 class="title">Employee Background Tracking</h4>
                    <p>
                        Details of Employee presence on different days.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div onclick="location.href = '../Client/EmployeeTrackRouteEstimateList';" class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 noselect">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="image"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h4 class="title">Employee Track Route & Estimate</h4>
                    <p>
                        Details regarding traveling details, traveling report and conveyance calculation.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div onclick="location.href = '../Client/TravelCostManage';" class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 noselect">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="image"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h4 class="title">Manage Base Travelling Cost</h4>
                    <p>
                        Details regarding traveling cost of the company. This is a rough calculation and different employees are assigned different amounts for travelling modes.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div onclick="location.href = '../Client/EmployeeEnquiryReport';" class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 noselect">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="image"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h4 class="title">Employee Visit Report</h4>
                    <p>
                        Reports of employee visits.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div onclick="location.href = '../Client/ChatWithEmployee';" class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 noselect">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="image"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h4 class="title">Chat with Employee</h4>
                    <p>
                        You can send messages and view replies from you Employees.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div onclick="location.href = '../Client/UnlockModules';" class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 noselect">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="icon">
                <div class="image"><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i></div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h4 class="title">Unlock Modules</h4>
                    <p>
                        Unlock or Activate modules. Also can temporarily turn of unwanted modules.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and **disabling Browser Link** in **Visual Studio** fixed it for me. From what I observed on the console, Browser Link runs some Javascript which shifts the page. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is something wrong with my system. Works perfectly in other pcs.

I used Webessential with autoreload on change options like that. May be my debugger problem.

Comment: I guess the same, sometimes such things happen when the scroll button of the mouse wears out.

Comment: @Balázs Nope, that doesn't seem to be the issue.